# Regex to extract <*n (where n is a number)

Tags: regex, go

I have a string of the form

`"abcd<*15<<defgj<*3fsdfsdf"`

I want to pull out all the `<` or `<*` followed by a number, e.g. `<*15`, `<*8`, `<*1` etc

I have this:

`<\*?[0-9+]?`

Which in the example strings matches

```
<*1
<
<
<*3
```

But I'd like it to match the first one as <*15

I thought the `+` did this in the regex, so I'm not sure why it's not working.

I also tried

`<\*?[\d+]?`

But still I get at most one digit following `<*`

A `<` will always either be on it's own, or followed by a `*` followed by a number. I want to capture `<6` as just `<`

If the `<` is followed by a `*`, but then no number. e.g. `<*abc` I would just want to capture `<`

Comment: `+` must be outside of brackets, but you want `*` instead: `<\*?[0-9]*`. Or, ``<(?:\*[0-9]*)?`` if the digit can only occur after `*`, and not right after `<`.

Comment: If you don't want to match `<6` eg without the `*` you will probably need something like this. `<(\*[0-9]+)?`

Comment: @NilsKähler Just as I wrote. `<(?:\*[0-9]*)?` or `<(?:\*\d*)?`

Comment: @TopologicalSort but it does not match `<`, nor `<*`.

Comment: I wouldn't want to match `<*` if the `*` isn't followed by a number. Is that possible ?

Comment: Looks like you really want `<(?:\*\d+)?`. `<` and then an optional sequence of `*` + one or more digits.

Comment: @Wiktor, you you are right, I think I must have posted before I saw your edit. But would `<(?:\*[0-9]*)?` not also match `<*` without a number following?

Comment: `<(?:\*\d+)?` @WiktorStribiżew, this looks perfect!

Comment: (<\*?[0-9]+)|(<\*)|< . The order matters.

Comment: Not every thing that can be done with a regexp should be done with a regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
<(?:\*\d+)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LQio7I/1).

*Details*:

- `<` - a `<` char
- `(?:\*\d+)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or zero repetition of a `*` char and one or more digits after it.

See the [Go demo](https://go.dev/play/p/LXQEVbm6Zp8):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`<(?:\*\d+)?`)
    matches := r.FindAllStringSubmatch("<*1 < <6", -1)
    for _, v := range matches {
        fmt.Println(v[0])
    }
}
```

Output

```
<*1
<
<
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `\<\*{1}\d+|\<`

explanation:

1. `\<` Match the lesser than char
2. `\*{1}` Followed by an asterix
3. `\d+` Followed by any number of sequential digits
4. `|\<` Or just match a `<` if the above does not match

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    pattern := regexp.MustCompile(`\<\*{1}\d+|\<`)

    inputString_1 := "abc<*15<<def<*3ghi"
    inputString_2 := "jkl<42<<mno<7pqrst"

    fmt.Println(pattern.FindAllString(inputString_1, -1))
    fmt.Println(pattern.FindAllString(inputString_2, -1))
}

// Output:
// [<*15 < < <*3]
// [< < < <]
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/xNmsrilYGRL

Regex: https://regex101.com/r/6TtLtl/1

Regarding your note...

> I thought the + did this in the regex `<\*?[0-9+]?` so I'm not sure why it's not
> working.

`[0-9+]?` greedily matches any digit *or* a "+" *or* an empty string.

see: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html

Comment: "*`[0-9+]?` means match any number of numbers or not*": No, it means either a digit/`+` character or empty string. `+` is inside the class so it's interpreted as literal, and `?` is greedy by default (`??` is its lazy version).